# Is there a conceptual reason why calling a method with a dynamic parameter always returns dynamic?

Tags: c#, syntax, compilation, dynamic-keyword

I can imagine this would be a problem with multiple overloads, but (besides Linq) a big part of the code probably has only one overload.

When there is only one overload it can save extra casting boilerplate, avoiding errors like `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.` in situations.

Of course you could argue that when you add an overload at a later stage the code would i.e. start triggering the above compiler error again. But then again - adding overloads can also break typed behavior (with i.e. multiple interfaces).

Is this just not a priority (for now) or am I missing some conceptual problem? I'm asking this to learn more about language design.

```
static int MapLolCats(int amountOfLolcats, Func<dynamic,int> mappingFunction)
{
    return mappingFunction(amountOfLolcats);
}

// This works as expected
var amountOfLegs = MapLolCats(5, x => x * 4);

// This creates a compilation error (despite you could deduct what is meant, because there is only one overload)
// Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
dynamic jsonValue = 5;
var amountOfLegs = MapLolCats(jsonValue, x => x * 4);
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't have any compilation errors, I don't understand this question.

Comment: Hi @DavidG, I've updated the example - hopefully it's more clear what I mean

Comment: Have you considered using `Func<dynamic, int> g = x => x * 4;`?